# How to limit Row result on query when no Primary Key in table

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm new to SQL as for over 20 years I haven't touched a single code line, so it feels like starting over.

I have a database with two tables, one for Projects, and another one for the Milestones.  What I'm trying to achieve is to have a query that will retrieve the latest Milestone logged for each project.  That way I can build a report with one project line with the latest update only.

I've managed to build the query to retrieve 1 (One) Milestone Record for each project.  However when I've logged more than one update for the same date, the query returns all of them.  I've  tried to utilize the rowid, but it didn't work.

Here my sample tables:

[image: 1]

And the query I've tried to run that currently retrieves more than 1 record when milestone created the same date.

```
select  PROJECT_DATA.PARTNER_NAME as PARTNER_NAME,
  PROJECT_DATA.SOLUTION_STATUS as SOLUTION_STATUS,
  PROJECT_DATA.STRATEGY_MANAGER as STRATEGY_MANAGER,
  PROJECT_DATA.SOLUTION_TYPE as SOLUTION_TYPE,
  PROJECT_DATA.INTEGRATION_METHOD as INTEGRATION_METHOD,
  PROJECT_MILESTONE.MILESTONE as MILESTONE,
  PROJECT_MILESTONE.COMPLETED_ON as COMPLETED_ON,
  PROJECT_MILESTONE.NOTES as NOTES
       from PROJECT_DATA JOIN PROJECT_MILESTONE PROJECT_MILESTONE ON                                                       PROJECT_DATA.ID=PROJECT_MILESTONE.PROJECT_ID
       where PROJECT_MILESTONE.COMPLETED_ON = (Select MAX (PROJECT_MILESTONE.COMPLETED_ON)
                                   FROM PROJECT_MILESTONE
                                   WHERE PROJECT_DATA.ID=PROJECT_MILESTONE.PROJECT_ID)
```

Any help on how to limit the query result to just 1 (newest one) when logged in the same date, will be extremely helpful.

Comment: Please provide a few rows of sample data and the expected result. You don't need to add all the columns in the example, but only the relevant ones.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that Completed on has the time as well along with the date, all you need to do is select top 1 in the **ORDER BY DESC**

Something like

```
    select top 1  PROJECT_DATA.PARTNER_NAME as PARTNER_NAME,
  PROJECT_DATA.SOLUTION_STATUS as SOLUTION_STATUS,
  PROJECT_DATA.STRATEGY_MANAGER as STRATEGY_MANAGER,
  PROJECT_DATA.SOLUTION_TYPE as SOLUTION_TYPE,
  PROJECT_DATA.INTEGRATION_METHOD as INTEGRATION_METHOD,
  PROJECT_MILESTONE.MILESTONE as MILESTONE,
  PROJECT_MILESTONE.COMPLETED_ON as COMPLETED_ON,
  PROJECT_MILESTONE.NOTES as NOTES
       from PROJECT_DATA JOIN PROJECT_MILESTONE PROJECT_MILESTONE ON
      PROJECT_DATA.ID = PROJECT_MILESTONE.PROJECT_ID
order by COMPLETED_ON DESC
```

Also, the joining condition has to be specified after the **"ON"** in joins and then you can use where condition to filter out the data

Comment: Completed_On only have the date without the time.  Not sure why I've got an error when using top1.  I've tried also with Fetch 1 Row only, but didn't work either.